# unable to send email via gmail

Tags: c#, gmail

I am trying to send via gmail in c# using stmp.gmail.com but keep on getting authentication 5.5.1 issue under port 587 and under port 465 i get an operation timed out.

Please see my code and let me know how and where I am going wrong and how to resolve.

thanks

```
private void SendMessage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var connected = ConnectedToInternet();
        if (!connected) return;

        var Client = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 465,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Password),
            Timeout = 20000
        };

        var m = new MailMessage { Subject = txtSubject.Text, IsBodyHtml = true, Body = txtMessage.Text };
        foreach (var email in LbEmailAddresses.Items)
        {
            try
            {
                m.To.Add(new MailAddress(email.ToString().Trim()));
                m.From = new MailAddress(txtUserName.Text);
                Client.Send(m);
                m.To.Clear();
                Success.Add(email.ToString());
            }
            catch (SmtpException esException)
            {
                Errors.Add("Error sending to " + email + " " + esException.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Errors.Add("Error sending to " + email + " " + ex.Message);

            }

        }
        var message = new StringBuilder();
        message.AppendLine(Success.Count() + " Sent Successfully");
        message.AppendLine(Errors.Count() + " Errors Click See Error Log for more information");
        if (CustomMessageBox.ShowYesNo(message.ToString(),
            "Result",
            "Ok",
            "View Log") != MessageBoxResult.No) return;
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter("log.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var error in Errors)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(error);
            }
            Process.Start("log.txt");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried port 25 ?

Comment: no, as i was looking to use SSL, but will try that now

Comment: this might explain some of it just got an email from google about an app that was blocked.
Please review your Account Activity page at https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity to see if anything looks suspicious. Whoever tried to sign in to your account knows your password; we recommend that you change it right away. 

If this was you
You can switch to an app made by Google such as Gmail to access your account (recommended) or change your settings at https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps so that your account is no longer protected by modern security standards.

Answer (score 0):

My comment above about the email from google...  need to make the account less secure if youre going to be sending from c# or other google approved apps.